# Invalid Pointer Operation - Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-berlin

Eu adicionei um TClientDataSet(cdsTemp) na tela do meu Form, bom, e eu implemento os fields desse TClientDataSet(cdsTemp) via código, dessa maneira:

`for i := 0 to (cdsAux.Fields.Count - 1) do
    cdsTemp.Fields.Add(cdsAux.Fields[i]);`

Repare que eu vou jogando os fields do cdsAux para o cdsTemp, não sei se é a maneira correta de fazer, mas é a que eu achei, adaptei e está funcionando.

Até ai está tudo certo e funcionando, porém, quando eu executo a aplicação ele passa os campos do cdsAux para o cdsTemp de boa, mas quando fecho o form da o erro "Invalid Pointer Operation". Se eu comentar a procedure que está fazendo esse procedimento de jogar os campos do cdsAux para o o cdsTemp o erro não acontece mais.

Ou seja, o problema, aparentemente está ai, gostaria de saber se estou esquecendo alguma coisa, se estou fazendo alguma coisa de errado, se alguém já passou por isso etc.

Comment: Delphi e seus errinhos que nos deixam com dor de cabeça kkk
Brincadeiras a parte, você já tentou fechar ou destruir esse cdsTemp antes de fechar o formulário?

Comment: Em qual evento do form você esse trecho de código?

Comment: @RobertoFagundes Pois é, rapaz kkkkkk Sim, Sim já tentei dar um FreeAndNil(cdsTemp) no OnClose e no OnDestroy do Formulário e nada ainda.

Comment: @PabloVargas Eu uso na ação de um botão específico aqui na minha aplicação. Basicamente no Incluir do meu formulário, pois estou precisando fazer esse procedimento ai para uma ação que estou testando. Mas esse erro está me atrapalhando rs

Comment: @HenriqueTavares o que eu acho que pode estar acontecendo, é que essa função ADD, não esta copiando o seu field, e sim só passando a referência, ou seja, quando você destrói seu formulário, ele automaticamente destrói o seu cdsTemp(Isso se ele estiver dentro do seu formulário), e destrói a field do cdsAux, e ai que gera o erro. Então tente dar um clear no seu cdsTemp no evento onClose do seu formulário, desta forma: cdsTemp.Fields.Clear();

Comment: @RobertoFagundes opa, então, testei aqui o que você falou e ainda assim o erro persiste. Porém, eu fui debugando mais um pouco e descobri que aonde eu abro o meu formulário, nessa parte: 
`var
   loForm: TfrmTeste;
begin
   loForm  := TfrmTeste.Create(Self);
   try
      loForm.ShowModal;
   finally
      FreeAndNil(loForm);
   end;
end;`

Comment: O erro do Invalid Pointer Operation ocorre quando entra no FreeAndNil(loForm) no finally. Acho que ficou meio ruim de ver o código acima pq ficou deitado kkkk. O erro está envolvido com essa parte da função ADD e provavelmente do jeito que estou
trabalhando para abrir o formulário. Eu tava lendo alguns fóruns e vi que algumas pessoas comentaram dessa possibilidade da maneira que está se abrindo o form está influenciando nesse erro
vou dar mais uma olhada aqui e vê se descubro mais alguma coisa, muito obrigado pela sua atenção, de verdade!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie os campos da seguinte maneira (sendo que tamanho é uma variável *integer*):

```
for i := 0 to cdsAux.FieldCount -1 do
begin
  tamanho:= cdsAux.Fields[i].Size;
  if (cdsAux.Fields[i].DataType = ftString) and (tamanho = 0) then
    tamanho:=1
  else
    cdsTemp.FieldDefs.Add(cdsAux.Fields[i].FieldName,
          cdsAux.Fields[i].DataType, tamanho);
end;
```